uint8_t elements exceeding one byte?
I saw this code:
uint8_t broadcastAddress[] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};

I know uint8_t holds a byte, so how does this line of code work when a single
element, 0xFF, is in itself one whole byte and the array is therefore 6 bytes wide.
Can someone explain how 6 bytes of data are of type single byte?
To try and probe it, I wrote this code on an Arduino Uno R3:
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    // #include <stdint.h>  // Not needed in Arduino IDE with Arduino board selected.
    // #include <stdio.h>  // Not needed in Arduino IDE with Arduino board selected.
}

void loop() {
    delay(3000);
    uint8_t numbers[] = {0xFF, 0x22, 0xA0, 0x3B, 0xC2};  // 5 elements & 5 bytes

    Serial.print("sizeof(numbers) ");
    Serial.println(sizeof(numbers));   // outputs = 5, (obviously the # elements in array)

    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
        Serial.print("sizeof(numbers[");
        Serial.print(i);
        Serial.print("]: ");
        Serial.println(sizeof(numbers[i]));  // outputs 1 for i=0 to 8! Element value vanished! non-used elements positions equate to same as used element positions 
    }
}


The comment says that numbers[] is 5 elements. The compiler will count the values and fill in the correct number inside [], making it an array.

uint8_t type is 1 byte. The size of array of uint8_t is 1 * number of elements. sizeof(numbers) is the size of array. And btw you can write sizeof numbers. Parentheses are necessary only for sizeof of data type, e.g. sizeof (int) but sizeof my_variable.

If you do a Serial.println(sizeof(numbers)) it will print 5.


saw this code: uint8_t broadcastAddress[] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
0xFF, 0xFF};
I know uint8_t holds a byte, so how does this line of code work when a
single element, 0xFF, is in itself one whole byte and the array is
therefore 6 bytes wide.

broadcastAddress is not a uint8_t, but rather an array of uint8_ts ([] makes it an array).
It can therefore contain multiple elements of type uint8_t.
The compiler will determine the actual size of the array based on the initializer ({0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF}) - i.e. 6 in this case.
The same applies to numbers in your test code (with 5 elements).

For sizeof it doesn't really matter what "value" you apply it to. Only the type matters.
When you have
uint8_t foo[5];

each and every element of foo has type uint8_t and that is all sizeof cares about. It doesn't even look at what specific element you are using: it's just an element of foo
sizeof foo[-1]      // all
sizeof foo[1000]    // good

In the same way when 2 integers are divided the resulting value has type int
sizeof (1000/3)
sizeof (42/0)   // ok, sizeof just sees an int resulting from dividing 2 ints

